# Upgrading JAX-WS to a newer version in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-ws

We're experiencing a [classloader leak](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18787) when using web services in Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and would like to upgrade JAX-WS to a 2.2.7 that fixes this issue. Can you recommend a way to do this? We've tried putting `jaxws-rt.jar` to `${AS_HOME}/lib/endorsed` folder but then we are getting the following exception on deployment:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
```

I'm pressuming the problem is that this class is loaded by a different classloader.

How to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [installing a new version of Metro](http://metro.java.net/2.2.1-1/#installing) that contains JAX-WS 2.2.7, the problem was fixed.